# GetSingleNode on XML with namespace not working

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I need to work with the Global List from TFS. I've downloaded it, and have access to the xml, which has a namespace. I created a `XmlNamespaceManager`, but I am still having issues getting the node that I need. For those not familiar, the TFS Global List looks like this:

```
<gl:GLOBALLISTS xmlns:gl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/workitemtracking/globallists">
    <GLOBALLIST name="Builds">
        <LISTITEM value="..." />
    </GLOBALLIST>
...
    <GLOBALLIST name="Client Name">
        <LISTITEM value="Test" />
```

After downloading the Global List into an `XmlDocument`, I use the following code to try to extract a test node, but I am getting a null back.

```
Dim globalList As XmlDocument = store.ExportGlobalLists()
Dim nsManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(globalList.NameTable)
nsManager.AddNamespace("gl", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/workitemtracking/globallists")
Dim node As XmlNode = globalList.SelectSingleNode("//gl:GLOBALLISTS/gl:GLOBALLIST[@name='Client Name']/gl:LISTITEM[@value='" + Name + "']", nsManager)
```

As a side note, the name I am searching for does exist. I have also tried the following in the immediate window:

```
globalList.SelectNodes("/gl:GLOBALLISTS", nsManager)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
globalList.SelectSingleNode("//gl:GLOBALLISTS/gl:GLOBALLIST[name='Client Name']/gl:LISTITEM[value='" + Name + "']", nsManager)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
globalList.SelectSingleNode("//gl:GLOBALLIST[name='Client Name']/gl:LISTITEM[value='" + Name + "']", nsManager)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
globalList.SelectSingleNode("//gl:GLOBALLIST[name='Client Name']", nsManager)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
globalList.SelectSingleNode("//gl:GLOBALLIST", nsManager)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
globalList.SelectSingleNode("//gl:GLOBALLISTS/GLOBALLIST[name='Client Name']/LISTITEM[value='Test']", nsManager)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
globalList.SelectSingleNode("/gl:GLOBALLISTS/gl:GLOBALLIST[@name='Client Name']/gl:LISTITEM[@value='" + Name + "']", nsManager)
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
```

**SOLUTION**

I had to take out the namespace references except for the first node, and add the @ sign for accessing the attributes as suggested in the answer below.

```
Dim node As XmlNode = globalList.SelectSingleNode("//gl:GLOBALLISTS/GLOBALLIST[@name='Client Name']/LISTITEM[@value='" + Name + "']", nsManager)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath, attributes are indicated using `@`. That seems to be the reason you're having a problem, since you're not using `@`.

Also, as you've discovered on your own, only the outermost element is in a namespace, so only the first segment should have `gl:`.

```
Dim node As XmlNode = globalList.SelectSingleNode("/gl:GLOBALLISTS/GLOBALLIST[@name='Client Name']/LISTITEM[@value='" + Name + "']", nsManager)
```

Comment: Thank you. That got me part way there. I also realized that I should only reference the NS in the first node. I updated the bug to show the solution.

Comment: @Tim Ah, I hadn't noticed that about the XML, but I see it now. Only the outermost element has a namespace.